# How this is Working $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not getting the last line after $toggle please explain to me what is the use of  .indexOf(value) in this line.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: this is the actual code  
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  }); 
});

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48238205/edit) link below your question in order to add the code directly into the question. In the comments section it is basically unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to know what `.indexOf(value)` is doing?

From the documentation: [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

In this particular code snippet, `value` is whatever has been typed into `#myInput`, so `indexOf(value)` returns the index of whatever has been entered into `#myInput`

Now on the last line a `toggle` is called on the condition `indexOf(value) > -1`, so the rows in the table will be hidden if they do not contain the user's input.

Comment: thanks can you explain it in more details. $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)

Comment: only if I am writing -1 at the end then only it working WHY?

Comment: If `indexOf()` returns `-1` it means the string was not found, so you need to make sure its returning something greater than `-1`

Answer (score 2):

The toggle function can take a Boolean to decide whether to show or hide the selected element.
This code:

```
$(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1
```

merely resolves to either true or false.

Comment: Thanks for explain :)

Answer (score 2):

if you wanted to know about
`$(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)`
line, then you have to understand from the below section with some steps, then maybe it will be much clear to you. ( sorry to take long description)

Step 1:

```
 $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
```

Here

```
$("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
...
});
```

is checking every each row of #myTable table.

Step 2:

`$(this).text().toLowerCase()` is every time collecting all columns data from a row as lower case a large string.

Example: You can find out using the below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      alert($(this).text().toLowerCase());
    });
  });
});
```

Step 3:

`indexOf(value)` is a method to search the position of the given value from a string.

Example:

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.indexOf("welcome");
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_indexof

So whatever you search into `#myInput` , its searches his position from `$(this).text().toLowerCase()` lower case large string using
`$(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value)`
and returns the actual location or if he could not matched or find out then returns `-1` .
Which is checking into below line

```
$(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
```

Step 4:

Finally `$(this).toggle` is called on the condition `indexOf(value) > -1`, so the rows in the table will be hidden if they do not match with the user's searchable input.

Some use full links :

indexOf: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_indexof

toggle: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp